# profile belongs_to user but can't access user in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, acts-as-taggable-on

I have done this a million times and yet I can't seem to figure out why it is not working now.  I have a user model that has_one profile.  The profile belongs_to the user model.  In my profile controller, I am trying to access all the profiles that belong to a subset of users but I can't seem to.  I have tried this:

```
def index
    if params[:tag]
        @profiles = Profile.user.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
        @profiles = Profile.all
    end
end
```

I am getting the error that the method user is undefined.  Yet, in views, I have called @profiles.user and it works fine.  I have also tried:

```
def index
    if params[:tag]
        @profiles = Profile.users.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
        @profiles = Profile.all
    end
end
```

but that does not work. Please help.  Thanks.

EDIT:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile
    acts_as_taggable
end


class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: if the relationship is has_one then you would just be using user like in the first example. I would be curious to see your model definitions. also it would be nice to see your tagged_with method

Comment: Give us your models association declaration in User.rb and Profile.rb. Do you acts_as_taggable yours models ?

Comment: Just because you have a `user` field as part of your `Profile` definition, doesn't mean that you have class methods `user` or `users` on `Profile`.

Comment: I added the models.  The user model has acts_as_taggable.  The profile method does not because it does not have tags associated with it.  Dan, tagged_with isn't my method, its part of the acts_as_taggable_on gem.

Comment: Peter, just looked at the load error question.  I don't see any connection to my question.  Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry!  Posted on wrong question!  Will remove.

Comment: you added relationship belongs_to :user in Profile and has_one :profile in user model. But in Index method you have written Profile.users. As you mentioned has_one relationship how can you access users on Profile? and Also it is wrong you can't directly call users method on model Profile.

Comment: Not all users will have profiles.  I am trying to target all users that have profiles.  So my logic is profile.user (which has worked for me before in views).  I need to get to the user though because the tagged_with method only works on users.  So I go from profiles to users to the tagged_With method.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so would you mind marking it as answered?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `user` isn't a class method of Profile, it's an instance method. And

You need:

```
def index
 if params[:tag]
   @profiles = Profile.find(params[:profile_id]).user#whatever else you're trying to do
 else
   @profiles = Profile.all
end
```

But based on what you're saying in your followups you need something where you select the users from a join with profiles, then call `tagged_with`

Maybe

```
def self.users_with_profiles
 query = <<-SQL
    SELECT u.*
      FROM users AS u
      JOIN profiles AS p
        ON p.user_id = u.id
  SQL

  find_by_sql(query)
end
```

and then

```
def index
  @profiles = User.users_with_profile.tagged_with(params[:tag]).map {|user| user.profile }
end
```

Or it's probably simpler

```
def index
  @profiles = User.joins(:profile).tagged_with(:params).map { |user| user.profile }
end
```

This will return `Profile`s which is what I assume you're looking for since it's called on your `Profile` model.

If this doesn't get you all the way there I hope it at least gets you closer

Answer (score 0):

Try this by following steps,

```
   def index
      if params[:tag]
        # first find out users having tag = params[:tag]
        users = User.tagged_with(params[:tag])
        # collect ids of those users assume user_ids = array of ids
        user_ids = users.map(&:id)
        # then make query on profile model
        @profiles = Profile.where(user_id: user_ids) # get list of profiles            
      else
        @profiles = Profile.all
      end
   end
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't get me to the users.  I need to get to the users so I can use the acts_as_taggable method.

Comment: KD12, your answer does not include the tagged_with method.  Your comment will also target users that have not yet created a profile, which is not what I want.  Thanks for your help though, i think were getting close.

Comment: In question, you mentioned Profile.users.tagged_with(params[:tag]) what it returns users with profile or profiles of users having params[:tag]?

Comment: I thought it would return users but its not returning anything.

Comment: And what will be the return value of index method profiles or users? you have mentioned @profiles variable and you want users in @profiles?